# Why does async/await does not wait for node's http.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning Node.js now and I have this question about async stuff.

Here is a code:

```
const http = require("http"),
    [_, _1, url1, url2, url3] = process.argv;

let strings = '';

const fetchData = async () => {
    const firstReq = await http.get(url1, data => {
        data.on('data', chunk => {
            strings += chunk
        })
    });

    const logRes = await test()
    return firstReq
}

const test = () => {
    console.log(` --- `, strings);
}

fetchData();
```

I was expecting that node will make GET request to url, add chunks to variable and then call next `await` step that will `console.log` resulted string with data.

Now code execution just prints empty string.

Why async/await does not work here? It is because `http.get()` does not return anything?

Thanks!

Comment: You can only `await` something that is a Promise

Comment: Use fetch API instead